struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 81 bytes
In the following code, the top level is parse(), and there are some manipulations done to the unpacker and payload arguments that get fed into the unpack_data, which ultimately breaks with the error in the title.
def parse(exg, protocol, data): 
    ....

    if len(payload) < protocol.length_size:
        # Chunk of data is cut right after the header, no payload to get the first byte/s
        # to see how big the payload is.
        # I/O needs to read the next chunk
        break

    length_bytes = payload[:protocol.length_size]
    length = unpack(protocol.length_unpack_str, length_bytes)[0]

    if len(payload) < length:
        # Not enough data to read the full application message.
        # I/O needs to read the next chunk.
        break

    # Keep only the data that we are interested on from the message (fields with data)
    # and keep the rest to analyse on the next iteration.
    payload, data = payload[protocol.length_size+protocol.type_size:length], payload[length:]

    # Get the appropriate message unpacker
    message = protocol.messages.get(msg_type)

    self.check_seq_no_increment(exg, seq_no

    # Unpack the payload and store the message
    if not message:
        exg.logger.error(f"No unpacker found for {msg_type}")
        continue
    try:
        # Unpack the message values here
        values = protocol.unpack_data(message.unpacker, payload)


def unpack_data(self, unpacker, payload):
    """
    Unpack binary data from buffer given to the format specified.

    Parameters
    ----------
    unpacker: str
        Format to unpack the data into
    payload: bytes
        Data to unpack

    Returns
    -------
    tuple
        Values unpacked as per format specified.
    """
    try:
        output = unpack(unpacker, payload)
    except:
        breakpoint()

    return output

In the unpack_data() function above, I am getting a struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 81 bytes
When I print the unpacker -> <IIqqqIqI8sBqqq
When I print payload -> <memory at 0x7fc14631fa00> , print(len(payload)) -> 137
Any ideas how I can overcome this issue? (I wasn't sure how to inspect the payload too)

[SO]: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Check [SO]: How do I ask a good question? or
[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))
for more asking related details.
Also, [JonSkeet.CodeBlog]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION might be a good point to start.
Show the contents (length) of your data. Also, try using unpack_from instead of unpack.

Thanks @CristiFati am I right to think that all that is missing is the payload, then there is a minimal reproducible answer?

I wasn't sure how to inspect the payload - at the bottom of my question I write what I see when I print(payload). I believe with this information the example is reproducible?

print(len(payload)) can be helpful. Where do payload and the packer format string come from?

Thanks @MichaelButscher I've added it to the question the length is 137.
I've added a bit more of the code, the parse() function in particular. The code is quite long, so if there is a particular part I should share let me know :)

@CristiFati Using unpack_from can hide an error as supernumerary bytes in the buffer are silently ignored.

Is there some specification of the structure of the binary data? In other words: Why do you expect that the message follows the structure given in the unpacker?

@MichaelButscher I've added more code leading up the the call to unpack_data, does that help at all? or if I print more things out

I guess that the code alone won't help. It is based on some sort of specification of a device or other software sending messages, right? There seems to be some mismatch between code and specification which is hard to find here.

So if you only care about the 1st 81 bytes from payload you can safely do output = unpack_from(unpacker, payload) or output = unpack(unpacker, payload[:calc_size(unpacker)]). It's the same thing.If not, you'll have to provide more details about the expected behavior, data format, ....

Thanks a lot guys, I think the problem lies in the encoding and protocol. Something that I get from a third party.
